# Handling special characters in $.parseJSON

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

net application i'm getting a dictionary of values from database and passing them from code behind to script. i'm accesing these values in script as

```
var dictionary = $.parseJSON('<%=DictionaryJson %>');
```

Here DictionaryJson is passed from asp.net and is passed like this

```
public string DictionaryJson 
        {
            get
            {

                //i'm getting dictionary information into Dictionaryinformation then
                JavaScriptSerializer jSer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                return jSer.Serialize(Dictionaryinformation);

            }
        }
```

and this is seen like following when application is run and DictionaryJson value is fetched

```
var dictionary = $.parseJSON('{"Name1":"Description1","Name2":"Description2"}');
```

The data that is passed into DictionaryJson is already parsed but i'm using another statement `

```
var data = eval(DictionaryJson);
```

If i don't use $.parseJSON and uses following code

```
var dictionary ='<%=DictionaryJson %>';
 var data = eval(DictionaryJson);
```

then eval is throwing an error saying missing ';'

but if i use $.parseJSON then this statement is  throwing an error when any one of Name1,Name2,Description1,Description2 contains any special character like singlequotes ('), or back slash (). It is throwing error. I want to solve this special characters case but i still wanted them to be there in the text as they are part say Name1 may be like Id/Number.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the following method

```
public static MvcHtmlString WriteVariables(this HtmlHelper helper, Dictionary<String, Object> values, Boolean writeVar = true) {
    var sb = new StringBuilder("<script type=\"text/javascript\">//<![CDATA[\r\n");
    var seriazlier = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    if (writeVar)
        sb.Append("var ");
    for (var i = 0; i < values.Count; i++) {
        var key = values.Keys.ElementAt(i);
        sb.Append(key).Append("=");
        var currentVal = seriazlier.Serialize(values[key]);
        sb.Append(currentVal).Append(i < values.Count - 1 ? "," : ";");
    }
    sb.Append("//]]></script>");
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString());
}
```

and use it as follows

```
@WriteVariable(new Dictionary<String, Object>{
    {"MyVar", "SomeStr"},
    {
        "ComplexObject", new {
            Property = true
        }
    }
});
```

In JavaScript I can use them as follows

```
DoSomething(window.MyVar);
DoAnotherThing(window.ComplexObject.Property);
```

This gives you a strongly typed control over your C# <=> JavaScript transmissions.

Currently I'm using Razor, but it is fully applicable to the ASPX view engine.